# SQL Query not returning rows when count(*) = 0 with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that returns the name of the school, the year of the payment, the cost of the payment and the number of students there was the year of the payment.
The problem I encounter is that for a certain year there is 0 student so the query doesn't return any row although there was a payment.

Here is what i tried :

```
SELECT School.NAME,
       Payment.year,
       Payment.amount,
       Count(Student.id_stud) AS 'nb stud'
FROM   School
       LEFT JOIN Student
              ON school.id_school = Student.id_school
       LEFT JOIN Payment
              ON School.id_school = Payment.id_School
WHERE  Year(Student.date_in) <= Payment.year
GROUP  BY School.NAME,
          Payment.amount,
          Payment.year
```

I want to display every row even if the COUNT(Student.id_stud) is 0.
I think that the problem is with the WHERE clause .

Comment: Both answers of Jatin C and Pரதீப் make sense and seem to work on my end. Perhaps consider sharing some `DECLARE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` so that all of us can replicate the issues together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `Year(Student.date_in)` filter to `ON` condition

```
SELECT School.NAME,
       Payment.year,
       Payment.amount,
       Count(Student.id_stud) AS 'nb stud'
FROM   School
       LEFT JOIN Student
              ON school.id_school = Student.id_school   
       LEFT JOIN Payment
              ON School.id_school = Payment.id_School
             AND Year(Student.date_in) <= Payment.year
GROUP  BY School.NAME,
          Payment.amount,
          Payment.year
```

Where you filter the `Year(Student.date_in)` in `Where` clause, for the non matching `Student.date_in` will have `NULL` values. Those `NULL` values will be filtered by the `where` condition. So Move the filter to `ON` clause it tells what are records to be joined instead of filtering the result. Same logic will be applied to `Payment.year` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With this query I get a row for the schools with no payment and no students. But the rows with the schools with a payment but no students that year doesn't show up

Answer (score 1):

There could be two reasons why there are not any result 
1. The value of the field which is used in the comparison is null
2. There is left join so there is a chance that there may not be the matching record for Student or Payment so if those are used in where condition then there must be matching record. you can try below query which is checking for null value as well.

```
SELECT School.NAME,
       Payment.year,
       Payment.amount,
       Count(Student.id_stud) AS 'nb stud'
FROM   School
       LEFT JOIN Student
              ON school.id_school = Student.id_school
       LEFT JOIN Payment
              ON School.id_school = Payment.id_School
WHERE  Year(Student.date_in) <= Payment.year
OR Student.date_in is null OR Payment.year is null
GROUP  BY School.NAME,
          Payment.amount,
          Payment.year
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As Pரதீப் 's query, i get the rows for the schools with no payment and no students but I don't get the rows with schools who got a payment a certain year with no students that year